# Loading a page with load indicator

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

Trying to make a loading indicator for web applications
I want to first call the blank html page and indicator loader, and then the server code, other aspx page.
 
I need to display loading indicator,runtime server code.   
when finishing. Clear loader indicator
Any tips, link or code example would be useful.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try pace: http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/

Comment: How to load html page and after aspx master page?

Comment: **Rick S.** People like you, will always! And this is bad!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice utility called [PACE](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/) which handles this very nicely.

It also takes asynchronous calls like REST and ajax into account.
Just include the script andere styles and you're done

```
<script src='pace/pace.js'></script>
<link href="pace/themes/pace-theme-barber-shop.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```